# Adding user-inputted values together and printing them

Tags: java, arrays, string, sum

I need to add values of a user-inputted string together for this program as a Java project. I've tried parsing but it doesn't seem to work, and I can't think of many other simple ways to find the sum of the string values and print them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int length;
        int counter;
        int sum = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers will you enter"); // input prompt
        length = input.nextInt();

        String[] number = new String[length];

        for (counter = 0; counter < length; counter++) {
            System.out.print("Number " + (counter + 1) + ": ");
            number[counter] = input.next();
        }

        input.close();

        System.out.print("The summation of ");
        for (counter = 0; counter < length - 1; counter++) {
            System.out.print(number[counter] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print("and " + number[counter] + " is: ");

        System.out.print(""); // How would I go about printing a sum ofthe values of the string?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write below logic :

```
for(int i=0;i<number.length;i++){
    try{
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(number[i]);
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {

    }
}
System.out.println("The sum is:"+sum);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but would you mind explaining how the "catch" bit works? I'd  been told to use parseInt before to grab the value of a string but previous attempts resulted in an error saying that the "method " was undefined

Comment: Can you show those errors, by the way above way looks quite good to me .

Comment: @JordanSullivanIII parseInt(String s) method throws NumberFormatException if  the string does not contain a parsable integer.. so to handle that exception by your code catch clause is added. you can go through exception handling and refer java doc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

include: `sum += Integer.parseInt(number[counter])` in your for loop and print it at last

```
for(counter = 0; counter < length-1; counter++){
  System.out.print(number[counter] + ", ");
  sum += Integer.parseInt(number[counter]);
 }
```

```
System.out.print(sum); // How would I go about printing a sum ofthe values of the string?
```

Comment: Interesting.. this has very similar to the code below that worked but upon entering it I get a syntax error and another error saying that parseInt cannot be resolved or is not a field. Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: try is now there was unnecessary `.` dot in my code

Answer (score 0):

Using [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) (introduced in Java 8) you can get the sum writing one line:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(number).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
```

Comment: Upon inputting this line I get the errors:
"Arrays cannot be resolved", 
"number cannot be resolved to a variable", 
and "Method references are only allowed at Source level 1.8 and above."

Comment: First you need to import the class Arrays: `import java.util.Arrays;`  If you're using Eclipse you also need to set the project's "Compiler compliance level" to at least "1.8". You find this in the Project Properties / Java Compiler.