# Using loops for both input and output

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, java.util.scanner, user-input

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class basic{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter raduis : ");
        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
            float num = sc.nextFloat();

        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
            System.out.println(num[i]);
        }
            
    }
}
```

How can we take input from the user using loops and add all the user input and show's the output, for example, I have to take 3 user inputs (`54, 6, 432`), add all of them, and then show the output(`432`). I have tried but then I stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding user-inputted values together and printing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738816/adding-user-inputted-values-together-and-printing-them)

Comment: @GauthamM I mean using for loop i will take user input lets says 3 times and then I will add the user input and then I have to show the input to that you have entered this & this and sum of this is this.I hope am able to understand you.

Comment: The question mentioned does that. In the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52738816/7804477) you can see the code to display the entered numbers and in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52738898/7804477) explains how to find the sum.

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem?  If not, leave a comment. If yes, make sure to encourage answerers of helpful answers by upvoting their answers(click on the up arrow on the left of the post) and mark one of the answers as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable (`sum`). You first initialize it to 0. And in the loop immediately after you get the input from the user for each value, add the input to this variable. Such a variable is sometimes referred to as an *accumulator* and the operation can be termed as an *accumulation* or *reduce*. If you want to store the values to display them later, you can use an array to store the values while they are being input and being summed. Also, in Java, the usual naming convention for class names is `PascalCase`, so consider naming it `Basic`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Basic {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        float sum = 0;
        float[] array;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of values: ");
        int count = sc.nextInt();
        array = new float[count];
        for(int i=0;i< count;i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter value " + i+1 + ": ");    
            float num = sc.nextFloat();
            array[i] = num;
            sum += num;
        }
        System.out.print("You have entered: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < count;i++) { 
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter raduis : ");
    int num[],sum=0;
    num = new int[3];
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
          num[i] = sc.nextInt();
          sum=sum+num[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in too many ways, it depends on the case, etc.

## Keep it simple solution

A simple solution could be creating a new variable `sum` to make the sum of everything, and just iterate the loop once:

```java
System.out.println("Enter raduis : ");

float sum = 0; // create a new variable to make the sum later
for(int i=0; i<=2; i++) {
    float num = sc.nextFloat();
    sum += num; // sum the current 'sum' value and 'num'
}

System.out.println("Result is: " + sum); // show the result
```

## Keep it clean solution

If for some reason you are required to execute this logic into separated parts, you can use an array of values to collect the `raduis` and then, make the sum operation over the values of that array.

I suggest you use a method for that cause it will help you to uncouple the logic of `asking numbers` and `make the sum operation` very easy.

```java
float[] askRaduis(int size) {
    System.out.println("Enter raduis :");

    float[] result = new float[size]; // create an array of floats
    for(int i=0; i<=size; i++) { // Iterate until reaching 'size'
        float num = sc.nextFloat();
        result[i] = num; // save the iteration number at the array
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then, with this method, you can ask the numbers and later process the sum operation. Something like this:

```java
float[] raduis = askRaduis(3); // Specify the amount of 'raduis' you want to ask.

float sum = 0; // create a new variable to make the sum later
for(float number : raduis ) { // this is a foreach loop it will iterate values of an array
    sum += num; // sum the current 'sum' value and 'num'
}

System.out.println("Result is: " + sum); // show the result
```